# show progress bar on grid view page index

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

I want to show progress bar on grid view page index. I have already displayed a progres bar on button click. I want to show the same when the user changes from 1 to 2. This is the modal pop-up i have used :

```
    <asp:Panel ID="PanLoad" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"  DisplayAfter="0">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div align="center">
     <img src="Images/icon_Loading.gif" id="ImgLoading" alt="loading" runat="server" />
<br />
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
```

I have used a javascript function and called it in a button click.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ShowModalPopup(ModalBehaviour) {
            $find(ModalBehaviour).show();
        }

        function HideModalPopup(ModalBehaviour) {
            $find(ModalBehaviour).hide();
        }        
    </script>
```

Help me to achieve it on gridview paging. ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Initialize and End Request of the Update Panel as:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
   $find('ModalBehaviour').show();      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
   $find('ModalBehaviour').hide();
}
```

About this events on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384136(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But how does it help in gridview paging? Can you pleas explain me. I want to shoe the progress bar on gridview paging. ThankYou.

Comment: @Anu When you try to change the page number the InitializeRequest is called, and when the page is finish and you have get the results the EndRequest is called. This functions exist in the UpdatePanel